# if else statement return a string, error.

Tags: java

why do i get an error, is it because im missing a return after the if checks? could i resolve it by setting one last return to null

```
public static String whoWins(rockPaperScissors user, rockPaperScissors computer){

    if(user == ROCK && computer == SCISSORSS){
        return "user wins";
    }
    if(user == PAPER && computer == ROCK){
        return " user wins";
    }
    if(user == SCISSORSS && computer == PAPER){
        return "user wins";
    }
    if(computer == ROCK && user == SCISSORSS){
        return "computer wins";
    }
    if(computer == PAPER && user == ROCK){
        return "computer wins";
    }
    if (computer == SCISSORSS && user == PAPER){
        return "computer wins";
    }
}
```

Comment: what if `user == null`? Then it wouldn't know what to return.

Comment: yes you need a non-conditional return

Comment: `"why do i get an error"` - Actually bothering to read the error message might help answer that.  The system is telling you what the problem is.  Why would you be ignoring it and asking us instead?

Comment: If you already know the answer, then why the question?

Comment: `why do i get an error, is it because im missing a return after the if checks? could i resolve it by setting one last return to null` Why didn't you just **try exactly that and find ouit**?

Comment: i guess my wording was poor, its not an error. Its telling me that im missing a return statement. And that return statement needs to be outside of the conditional checks.

Comment: How is that not an error?

Comment: i just noticed im not handling ties, i can add default conditional check and add a return "tie" statement

Comment: that doesnt work, as it continues to fall trough the if logic and reads only the tie statement.

Comment: Nice got it to work!. Thanks alot for your help guys.

Answer (score 2):

You get an error because your method does not always return a result. For example, what happens if `user == null`?

In my opinion, the cleanest way to handle this is to throw an exception because you should not reach the last line. `IllegalArgumentException` is a good candidate because the problem would come from invalid arguments passed to the method.

```
public static String whoWins(rockPaperScissors user, rockPaperScissors computer){
  [...]

  if (computer == SCISSORSS && user == PAPER){
    return "computer wins";
  }

  throw new IllegalArgumentException(...);
}
```

Comment: im doing this as a gui, and i should account for every possible combination of the rock paper sicssorss game.

Comment: @user1066367 `null` is not a valid combination but is syntactically valid. That is why you syntactically need to handle the case even if you *know* (but the compiler does not) that it cannot happen.